# Python: Modifying an object by assigning it to another object

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, assignment-operator, mutability

I'm new to Python (coming from C++), and understand that roughly speaking, all variables (names) are references to Python objects. Some of these objects are mutable (lists), while others aren't (tuples, although you can change its elements if they themselves are mutable).

For mutable objects, I can modify them by accessing their modifier functions (such as `.append()`) through the name(s) they're bound to. For example:

```py
myList = [1,2,3,4]
myList.append(5)
```

However, I know that simply assigning `myList` to a second list just instantiates this second list and reassigns `myList` to it; The original list `[1,2,3,4]` still exists, until garbage collection cleans it up (or not if another name is assigned to it).

**MY QUESTION:**

Lets say I have a `Point` class:

```py
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

p1 = Point(1,1)
p1.x = 2
p1.y = 2
```

How can I replace `p1.x = 2` and `p1.y = 2` with a single command that just assigns my `Point(1,1)` object to a `Point(2,2)` object? Clearly, `p1 = Point(2,2)` doesn't work as this just reassigns the p1 name to a new and different `Point(2,2)` object (which is not what I need!).

Is there a built-in way to do this or do I need to define an additional modifier function in `Point`:

```py
def changePoint(self, newPoint):
    self.x = newPoint.x
    self.y = newPoint.y
```

in order to do this in a single command (i.e. via `p1.changePoint(Point(2,2))`)? In C++ you can often just use a class' implicitly defined overloaded assignment operator (`operator=`) and accomplish this in a single command:

```cpp
SimpleNameClass* objectPtr = new SimpleNameClass("Bob");
//Dereferencing objectPtr and assigning new object:
*objectPtr = SimpleNameClass("Jim");

//Now objectPtr still points to (references) the same address in memory,
//but the underlying object is completely different.
```

Overall, it seems tedious to have to change every attribute individually when I want to transform my object into a new one, especially if my object contains many attributes!

**EDIT:**

Adding to Jainil's answer, it turns out I don't even need to change the definition of init at all, I can just use the above version. Then, you can transform a Point object to another one with a single command, like so:

```py
p1.__init__(2,2) #Replaces p1.x = 2, p1.y = 2
```

It works since the original init takes to 2 args. So a standard, vanilla init method basically already enables changing the underlying object, in addition to instantiating it (at least in this case). Yipee.

Comment: in python = can't be overloaded and it is not an operator in python, it is delimeter in python. see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#delimiters

Comment: = is delimeter , not an operator in python.

Comment: due to immutable classes , as you are saying python is not efficient language.

Comment: p1 = Point(2,2) is only way, and it is not efficient , as python dont have pointers concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        if(len(args)==2):
            self.x = args[0]
            self.y = args[1]
        elif(len(args)==1):
            self.x=args[0].x
            self.y=args[0].y




p1 = Point(1,1)
p1.x = 2
p1.y = 2
p1.__init__(Point(3,3))
print(p1.x," ",p1.y)
```

it is just what you want , but in python way.

in python = can't be overloaded and it is not an operator in python, it is delimeter in python. see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#delimiters

Comment: Really like the idea of just using the init method for this, it makes sense and doesn't require an additional method. This way init is more generalized and works not just for instantiating a new Point object but also when you simply want to change the original object to a new one.

Comment: Btw, I added a 2nd elif() inside init, now it also works when instantiating an empty Point() object, i.e. p2 = Point() :)

Comment: Actually, I was playing around with the solution just now, and it turns out you don't even have to change the init method at all. You can just call it like this: p1._init_(3,3) and then the object p1 is referencing is modified! It works since the original init method accepts 2 arguments as well. I still accept your answer though since you suggested using the init method in the first place ;)

Comment: @AdmiralAdama i thought you want p1=point(3,3) ,overloading of = , so i tried to demonstrate a kind of overloading in python. you have used the word "OVERLOADING" in question , that's why my answer contains **args.

Comment: p1.__init__(3,3)   -------->this don't contains overloading concept. it solves the mutability problem.

Comment: I just want to be able to modify an object - specifically, replace it with a new object - with a single command. Doesn't have to mimic overloading, just want it to be a single command (instead of changing each attribute individually, which is tedious). I just mentioned overloading for C++ because that's how you would do it in C++. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's wrong with my suggested edit? It makes your init function more flexible ;)

Answer (score 3):

one way would be to assign using tuple unpacking:

```
p1.x, p1.y = 2, 2
```

or you could implement a setter method in your class:

```
def set_xy(self, x, y):
    self.x, self.y = x, y
```

but creating a new instance (for a class this simple) may make more sense:

```
p1 = Point(2, 2)
```

in python you can not override the assignment operator `=`.

Comment: why are all telling = as operator as it is delimeter according to python docs https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#delimiters

Comment: @JainilPatel agreed, in python "assignment operator" may not be the best choice of words (although it is also mentioned in [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=assigment%20operator#operators)). but your link points to the lexical analysis... functionally `+=` is clearly an operator (whereas in your link it is treated as a (lexical) *delimiter*).

Answer (score 1):

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def change_point(self, new_x, new_y):
        self.x = new_x
        self.y = new_y
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is necessarily encouraged, but you can directly modify the `__dict__` attribute of the object to modify it. That leads to a solution like:

```
def assign_to(obj_one, obj_two) -> None:
    fields = obj_one.__dict__  # Grab the field/value dictionary of the object

    for field_name, field_value in fields.items():
        obj_two.__dict__[field_name] = field_value  # Loop over obj_one's fields and assign them to obj_two
```

Then its use:

```
p1 = Point(1, 2)
p2 = Point(8, 9)

assign_to(p1, p2)

p2.x, p2.y  # To show that they were modified
# Prints (1, 2)

id(p1), id(p2)  # To show that they're both still distinct objects
# Prints (69029648, 69029296)
```

This may have drawbacks though, as honestly I've never played around with `__dict__` before. You may want to do further research into it before relying on it too heavily.

---

I'd honestly just write a custom assigning function as the other answers show. Writing an extra line per field shouldn't be too big of a deal; especially given most classes likely won't need such functionality anyways. You're likely just going to be copying PODs like this.

Comment: I like it, would definitely use after researching a bit more. +1 for unorthodox (imo) yet compact solution.